# Terminal is saying: cannot import name Post

Tags: python, django

Here is what the terminal says:

```
 File "/Users/carlosecharte/makeblog/blogone/posts/admin.py", line 8, in <module>
   from .models import Post
   ImportError: cannot import name Post
```

Models.py file

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 from __future__ import unicode_literals

 from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
  class Post(models.Model):pass
     title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     content = models.TextField()
     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_ad=True)


  def__unicode__(self):
     return self.title
```

admin.py file:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

How can I get the post app to go to my admin dashboard?

Basically how can I get it to import properly?

Comment: Why do you have the `pass` keyword in there after `class Post(models.Model):`? That might be the problem...

Comment: I took it out and it still does not work

Comment: he have extra space before the class too, please check your code and you have to use some good IDES like pycharm that detects errors

Comment: Please show the layout of the files in your project.

Comment: What do you mean the layout of the file?

Comment: The spacing is inside the file does NOT have extra space.

Comment: I mean, please show what folders you have in your project and what files those folders contain.

Comment: Send me your email and I will send you a screen shot of the files

Comment: Please add the screenshot to your question here, instead of emailing it. Text output (e.g. from the `tree` command) would be even better than a screenshot.

Comment: Here is link to the screenshot: http://cagecharte.com/frontendcertificate/

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, and the `pass` shouldn't be there, but apart from that your code looks ok. Make sure you have saved all your files and restarted your server so that you are running the latest version of the code.

Comment: My indentation is not like this on the actual file.... It is only messed up on here because they required me to indent the code by hand and came out messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in `admin.py`:

```
from .models import post

admin.site.register(post)
```